# How Q11 works when Base is 0v?

Tags: voltage, transistors, capacitor, diodes, voltage-regulator

[image]why base Q11 is 0V current is flowing into the base of Q11, allowing current to flow between the collector and emitter.

Comment: What is the purpose of this circuit. Please provide a complete diagram.

Comment: Looks like capacitor C28 couples AC signal while blocking DC, so the only things that set Q11 base voltage are the diode and resistor (next to R53, parallel with Q11 B-E junction). The diode prevents Q11 base going below ground (I assume that's what the bar symbol represents here)...but there's also the Q12 B-E junction across Q11 C-E... what is this circuit, some kind of noise generator or guitar distortion pedal?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the base of Q11 is at 0V. However the circuit is likely to use an AC or transient signal that exceeds 0.7V periodically and that will turn on Q11. You'd need more detail as to the purpose of the circuit or the rest of the schematic to understand this.

Note that the base of Q11 is clamped by the diode on it's base and cannot go below -0.7V.